coreldraw12 macro export in multiple png images for each group selected
im using coreldraw 12 macro vba version 6.3
i wanted to export multiple png images from each group i have selected, i have manage to export the png image, but the problem is there is a debug in this area
    ' Loops through all groups
    For i = 1 To gs.Count
    groupname = gs.Shapes(i).Name
    gs.Shapes(i).CreateSelection

i get the script also from here but the i think the vba script is higher version, which coreldraw12 only uses vba6.3 version
please help me, in this small part, im missing something here, i've been up all night, can't figure it out in this part, please help me thankyou
this is the complete code:
Sub testexport()
    Dim sr As ShapeRange
    Dim group As Shape
    Dim groupname As String, path As String, sfolder As String
    Set gs = ActiveSelectionRange
    Dim i As Long
    Set objFOLDER = Interaction.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set objMAIN_FOLDER = objFOLDER.GetFolder("C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\image")
    ' Loops through all groups
    For i = 1 To gs.Count
        groupname = gs.Shapes(i).Name

        gs.Shapes(i).CreateSelection

        ' Sets the export path and file name
        path = objMAIN_FOLDER & groupname & "_" & i & ".png"
        Dim expflt As ExportFilter
        Set expflt = ActiveDocument.ExportBitmap(path, cdrPNG, cdrSelection, 
        cdrRGBColorImage, 0, 0, 300, 300, cdrNormalAntiAliasing, False, True, True, 
        False, cdrCompressionNone)
    With expflt
        .Interlaced = True
        .Transparency = 0 ' FilterPNGLib.pngNone
        .InvertMask = False
        .Color = 0
        .Finish
    End With
    Next i
End Sub


i have figure it out, but there is a problem, it random export any group on a page, what part i'm missing here?
hope anyone can help me to figure this out
here is the code:
Sub cdrexportimagePNG()
    Dim sr As ShapeRange
    Dim s As Shape
    Dim groupname As String, path As String, sfolder As String
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set asr = ActiveSelectionRange
    
    Set objFOLDER = Interaction.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objMAIN_FOLDER = objFOLDER.GetFolder("C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\img")
    
    
    ' Loops through all groups
    For i = 1 To asr.Count

        For Each asr In ActiveDocument.Pages
        asr.Shapes(i).CreateSelection
        Next
        ' Sets the export path and file name
        path = objMAIN_FOLDER & "_" & i & ".png"
    Dim expflt As ExportFilter
    Set expflt = ActiveDocument.ExportBitmap(path, cdrPNG, cdrSelection, cdrRGBColorImage, 0, 0, 300, 300, cdrNormalAntiAliasing, False, True, True, False, cdrCompressionNone)
    With expflt
        .Interlaced = True
        .Transparency = 0 ' FilterPNGLib.pngNone
        .InvertMask = False
        .Color = 0
        .Finish
    End With
    Next i
End Sub

